# Find number of unique clients per X weeks (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data set:

| row | client | Date | Year | weeknum | Year&Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2022-09-09 20:48:03 | 2022 | 36 | 202236 |
| 2 | 4 | 2022-09-08 07:47:12 | 2022 | 36 | 202236 |
| 3 | 4 | 2022-09-06 14:19:15 | 2022 | 36 | 202236 |
| 4 | 4 | 2022-09-10 19:51:00 | 2022 | 36 | 202236 |
| 5 | 4 | 2022-09-07 14:17:31 | 2022 | 36 | 202236 |
| 6 | 4 | 2022-09-08 09:55:39 | 2022 | 36 | 202236 |
| 7 | 4 | 2022-09-08 09:56:21 | 2022 | 36 | 202236 |
| 8 | 4 | 2022-09-08 10:23:13 | 2022 | 36 | 202236 |
| 9 | 4 | 2022-09-08 12:18:39 | 2022 | 36 | 202236 |
| 10 | 4 | 2022-09-08 17:33:29 | 2022 | 36 | 202236 |
| 11 | 2 | 2022-09-17 23:06:32 | 2022 | 37 | 202237 |
| 12 | 2 | 2022-09-17 11:35:25 | 2022 | 37 | 202237 |
| 13 | 4 | 2022-09-16 22:09:00 | 2022 | 37 | 202237 |
| 14 | 4 | 2022-09-17 11:02:00 | 2022 | 37 | 202237 |
| 15 | 4 | 2022-09-14 16:14:12 | 2022 | 37 | 202237 |
| 16 | 4 | 2022-09-15 10:57:54 | 2022 | 37 | 202237 |
| 17 | 4 | 2022-09-15 15:32:00 | 2022 | 37 | 202237 |
| 18 | 2 | 2022-09-19 10:00:35 | 2022 | 38 | 202238 |
| 19 | 2 | 2022-09-23 23:07:57 | 2022 | 38 | 202238 |
| 20 | 4 | 2022-09-21 12:01:31 | 2022 | 38 | 202238 |
| 21 | 4 | 2022-09-22 12:15:00 | 2022 | 38 | 202238 |
| 22 | 4 | 2022-09-23 20:55:02 | 2022 | 38 | 202238 |
| 23 | 4 | 2022-09-24 20:22:04 | 2022 | 38 | 202238 |
| 24 | 6 | 2022-09-23 16:28:59 | 2022 | 38 | 202238 |
| 25 | 4 | 2022-09-26 11:52:18 | 2022 | 39 | 202239 |
| 26 | 4 | 2022-09-30 21:29:01 | 2022 | 39 | 202239 |
| 27 | 4 | 2022-10-03 12:45:19 | 2022 | 40 | 202240 |
| 28 | 4 | 2022-10-04 16:56:27 | 2022 | 40 | 202240 |
| 29 | 10 | 2023-05-06 00:01:35 | 2023 | 18 | 202318 |
| 30 | 2 | 2023-06-26 22:23:14 | 2023 | 26 | 202326 |
| 31 | 2 | 2023-07-03 12:36:30 | 2023 | 27 | 202327 |
| 32 | 6 | 2023-01-16 11:18:56 | 2023 | 3 | 20233 |
| 33 | 9 | 2023-03-04 11:52:23 | 2023 | 9 | 20239 |

I would like to create an extra column to calculate the number of unique clients that have driven at least once the past 4 weeks. Would be amazing if someone knows how to do that, I have tried various things based on online research but can't get it right still.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So get the current week number, subtract 4, then any weeknumber greater than that is what you need.

Comment: What does "past 4 weeks" mean? Within current week and preceding 3 weeks? Within 28 days prior to Date? What results do you expect from the data you have provided? Would `100*Year+weeknum` (so that, for example, bottom row is `202309` rather than `20239`) be a better way of calculating `Year&Week` than whatever you are currently using?

Comment: Yes I mean current week and 3 preceding weeks!

Comment: For rows 27 & 28 (202240) I would expect the new column value to be 3 (since client number 4, 6, and 2 have driven that week and the 3 preceding weeks).

Answer (score 0):

You need a mechanism to stop the same client being counted multiple times.

```
=IF(ROW()=MATCH(B2,B:B,0),IF(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$34,B2,C$2:C$34,">="&TODAY()-28)>=0,1,0),0)
```

Explained:

1. The first IF statement will determine whether this is the first occurrence of the client in the list, i.e. does the match row number equal the current row number.
2. If it's the first occurrence, COUNTIFS will count the number of entries in the last 28 days, if it's greater than 0 the IF statement will return 1, if not 0.
3. The answer to 'how many clients have driven at least once in the past 28 days' will be the sum of this new column where each unique client will have a maximum value of 1.

I recommend the '28 days' parameter is a named range somewhere else in your workbook so not to have a magic number in there. Depending on whether your data has headings you may need to edit the column references from row 2 to 1. Note: For the Row()=Match portion, the reference must always include row 1 otherwise you will have an out by 1 issue.